# How to setting nodes for making a shop sign (lighting)

Tags: modeling, rendering, node-editor, light

This is the model I made
[image: The model I made]
How to setting nodes for making shop sign if I want the shop sign lighting in the dark .Like the picture down below 
[image: Reference]

So I don't know how to let my texture light. 
Thanks for helping me !!

Comment: change the diffuse shader for an emission shader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cycles works with shaders that describe the interaction with light.

**BSDF** shaders
Describe light reflection, refraction and absorption at an object surface.

For more info read: [What is a BSDF?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/785/what-is-a-bsdf) and https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/materials/surface.html#bsdf-parameters

A Diffuse BSDF shader does not emit light.

You need a shader that does! So use an

**Emission shader**

Used to describe light emission at an object surface or in a volume.

[image]

More info: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/introduction.html?highlight=shader