# Extruded face has stretched material

Tags: materials, uv, extrude

I have a terrain surface and i extruded it downwards along the z axis. This resulted in the material being stretched at the side. How do I have the sides and bottom to not have any color at all?
I realise I am using 'materials' and 'texture' interchangeably as I m unaware of the differences.

[image]

I have tried:

1. UV editing > Unwrap > Project from view (bounds)
2. Tweaking material properties, ensuring that it is on 'clip', 'linear', 'flat'

Been trying to solve this and other problems for many weeks now. Any help would be great thank you.

[image]

Comment: select the faces you need to have a different material,  create the material you want and assign it to the faces

Comment: see this post: [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Comment: Regarding Material and Texture, maybe this can clear it up [texture-vs-material-vs-shader](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139971/texture-vs-material-vs-shader?r=SearchResults&s=2|69.0351)

Comment: Thank you very much. I have progressed alot since!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new material for the edges and sides of the object.

With the object selected, go into edit mode. Select all the face that you want to change the color of. Now in the material properties tab, you will see an "Assign" option. With the correct material selected, press assign.

Comment: Thank you very much. The instructions were very clear.